# Docker -> portainer: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint portainer

Tags: docker

First of all I should say that I'm new to docker. I'm running `Docker Community Edition for Windows` and I'm trying to install portainer.

https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows

However when running the `Quick start` commands I get errors below:

https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#quick-start

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker volume create portainer_data
portainer_data
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
ce460adac87eaf13f6f6a22557a9f2401807b70a932e863fa7762cd76a158fed
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint portainer (8ec237cb106a09525de8cd1eeb04a9247cadcf99552058885d9d5a6fa22e369d): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:9000:tcp:172.17.0.2:9000: input/output error.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

My first guess was that the port was already used but that does not seem too be the case. I'm running the command from an elevated PowerShell as Administrator so it should not be that either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarted the docker service and it worked...